# Not able to update an item in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to update the Bar Information for users by getting their details and setting the Bar instance. But every time I click on the link on my dashboard it redirects me to the dashboard which is what I used for the else statement if it is not a post method.

view.py

```
def UpdateUserBar(request):
    user = request.user.id
    bar = Bar.objects.get(user_id=user)
    form = UpdateBar(instance=bar)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateBar(request.POST,request.FILES, instance=bar)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/updatebar')
            messages.success(request, 'Bar Information Updated successfully')
        else:
            return redirect('/dashboard')
            messages.error(request, 'Only Post method is accepted')
    else:
        form = UpdateBar(instance=bar)
    context = {"form":form, "bar":bar}
    return render(request, "dashboard/super/landlord/update_bar.html", context)
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateBar(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = '__all__'
```

models.py

```
class Bar(models.Model):

    status = (
            ("open", "open"),
            ("closed", "closed"),
            ("pending", "pending"),
        )

    user_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    opening_time = models.TimeField()
    closing_time = models.TimeField()
    status = models.CharField(choices=status, default="pending", max_length=14)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/bars', default='images/bars/default.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

updatebar.html

```
{% load i18n widget_tweaks %}
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{ form.name.label }}:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" id="id_name" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{user.name}}" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{ form.user_id.label }}:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input id="id_user_id" name="user_id" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{user_email}}" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{ form.address.label }}:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{ form.address|attr:"class:form-control" }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{ form.opening_time.label }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{ form.opening_time | attr:"class:form-control"  }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{ form.closing_time.label }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{ form.closing_time | attr:"class:form-control"   }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{ form.status.label }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{ form.status| attr:"class:form-control" }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" form-group ">
        <div class="input-group col-lg-12 ">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{ form.image.label}}</label>

            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
                {{ form.image| attr:"class:form-control" }}                                    </div>
                
            </div><!-- input-group -->                                        </div>
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <center><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update Bar Info</button></center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

[image: Error Page]

Every time I try to access the visit the URL, it redirects me to the dashboard.

Comment: show us your html form

Comment: updated, check the question again

Comment: Form is rendered with GET request first, and you do not allow it to render

Comment: i don't undersand very much please as i am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so there's a couple of small problems here, first of all if you want to retreive only one object use `get` instead of `filter` because it will give you a `DoesNotExist` error if no object is found, when using `filter` will return an empty queryset which will make an error harder to trace.

Also in your `Bar` model I see `user_id` field which I presume is the owner of the `Bar`, you should name it something like `owner` or `user` for better readability.

Here is how I would write this view:

```
def update_user_bar(request): # use uppercase view names for class-based-views, if its a custom view, use regular variable names
    user = request.user # <------- change this 
    user_email = request.user.email
    bar = Bar.objects.get(user_id=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateBar(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=bar)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/updatebar')
            messages.success(request, 'Bar Information Updated successfully')
        else: # here is where your problem is, you need to fix your code indentation
            return redirect('/dashboard')
            messages.error(request, 'Only Post method is accepted')
    else: 
        form = UpdateBar(instance=bar) # assign your form here for better radability
    context = {"form":form, "user_email":user_email, "bar":bar}
    return render(request, "dashboard/super/landlord/update_bar.html", context)
```

**Update**

Also *Only Post method is accepted* message makes no sense because to access any view in your website you are using Http `GET` method before anything else :)

Comment: it seams you mistakely indented the context and return render under the last else statement. I am not sure if that is correct.

Comment: I have chnaged the views.py to your method now it renders the page with the information prefilled but after updating the fields and click update button, it sends me to the dashboard page with no save action taken.

Comment: that means that your form validation fails, try to debug ill be back shoryly

Comment: Also check your form html it looks like you have alot of unclosed divs, the form closing tag is way off its opener position

Comment: all divs are cloed Sir. I have checked that again

Comment: aha, actually you are missing one thing in your form initialisation, change this: `form = UpdateBar(request.POST, instance=bar)` to this `form = UpdateBar(request.POST,  request.FILES, instance=bar)`  since you have a FileField in your form you need to address that.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that earlier, I also noticed it when i kept debugging the issue. I had added the request.FILES but I got an error that "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." I have updated the question to show the page and the error

Comment: in your model try making your choices not strings but arguments like     
`status = (
            (open, "open"),
            (closed, "closed"),
            (pending, "pending"),
        )`

Comment: It gave this error "NameError: name 'active' is not defined".

Comment: probably because of the objects you ave created prviously, but actually nevermind that solution, what you have should work ok, it can be improved but that probably wont make much difference more on that here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226031/discussion-between-sldem-and-coderboy).